# scraping data from articles(author name)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, data-science, screen-scraping

as a part from a project,
I tried to extract author name from a journal I have institutional access. I need to iterate over every journal in each issue. firstly, I tried to extract author name from the tag I thought is most suitable, but got an error. The code I ran:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os



output = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\97254\\Downloads\\output.xlsx")


url = "https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17452759.2022.2111585"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

parent_div = soup.find("div", class_="NLM_contrib-group")
print(parent_div)
author_link = parent_div.find_all("a.href")

author_name = author_link.text

print(author_name)
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\97254\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Final_assignment.py", line 55, in <module>
    author_link = parent_div.find_all("a.href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'.
```

Which is the relevant tag from these [tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XgGu.png) in the article page and what is the correct method to find this tag and add it as a string to a list in with selenium library.

Comment: Somehow your 
parent_div is None, check the response if you get a correct result if yes check that the class is corret.

Comment: This website has cloudflare protection.

Answer (score 0):

This website has CloudFlare protection, which is by requests were getting blocked. Selenium can be used in this case.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = "https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17452759.2022.2111585"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.author')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
author_link = soup.find("a", {'class': 'author'}).get('href')
author_name = soup.find("a", {'class': 'author'}).text

print(author_name)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Zhonggang Wang
```